# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string when using stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute the following statement within the stored procedure

```
execute immediate 'insert into tmp_vw(TMP_SRC, SNAP_DATE) 
                   select TMP_SRC,Max(SNAP_DATE) as SNAP_DATE 
                   from tmp_demand group by TMP_SRC'
```

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

SNAP_DATE is of type Date and the values are of the format '2001-01-01'

Comment: either tmp_vw.SNAP_DATE or tmp_demand.SNAP_DATE must be a varchar2?

Comment: If `snap_date` is of type `DATE` then it does not have a "format".

Answer (score 1):

you must have TMP_DEMAND.SNAP_DATE as a varchar2.

eg.

```
SQL> create table tmp_vw(TMP_SRC varchar2(20), SNAP_DATE date);

Table created.

SQL> create table tmp_demand(TMP_SRC varchar2(20), SNAP_DATE varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format ='yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into tmp_demand select 'a', sysdate from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format ='dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into tmp_vw(TMP_SRC, SNAP_DATE) select TMP_SRC,Max(SNAP_DATE) as SNAP_DATE from tmp_demand group by TMP_SRC;
insert into tmp_vw(TMP_SRC, SNAP_DATE) select TMP_SRC,Max(SNAP_DATE) as SNAP_DATE from tmp_demand group by TMP_SRC
                                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

you need to change your temp table to date too to avoid the error.